# Overloading std::streambuf for escaping data

Tags: c++, stream, overloading, streambuf

I have an external library which is able to write a bunch of data by passing it a `std::ostream*` pointer. It writes in binary format

I want to write this data inside a text file, which contains other stuff, by converting it to hexadecimal or base64.

As the data written by the lib can be very large, I want to avoid writing the data to a memory buffer, then convert to text format. I would like to convert on the fly.

Therefore, I am searching how to overload std::streambuf for that purpose. I need to overload the `overflow` virtual function, and I found the necessary info for this.

The question is, should I write to the file's `ostream`, or directly to its `streambuf` which I can get using `rdbuf()`? Is it allowed to write directly to a `stream` `stringbuf`?

Thanks in advance!